# How to install python packages from older version to newer version?

Tags: python, bash, pip, package

i was working with python 3.7 and i installed recently python 3.8 in linux.

Is there any bash command or script that take a list of all packages of 3.7 and install it one by one in 3.8 version.

i want to avoid to do it by hand every package.

Note: i install them in my system not using venv.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/path_to_3.7_bin/python -m pip freeze > /home/packages_list.txt
```

then

```
/path_to_3.8_bin/python -m pip install -r /home/packages_list.txt
```

Comment: I had installed python from source so in my case i had to do, pip3.7 freeze> p.txt and then sudo pip3.8 install -r p.txt

Answer (score 1):

try https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

pip freeze > requirements.pip in the old version

pip install -r requirements.pip in the new version