# Is it possible to move pip packages from one python version to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have been using python 3.8 for quite some time , but now I want to use python 3.9. The problem is that I have a lot of packages installed in the 3.8 folder. Is it possible to "move" all these packages to the 3.9 folder? Or can anyone suggest me a better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling each module, due to potential compatibility issues.

Comment: See also https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/ though I'd watch out for compatibility issues as pointed out by @DapperDuck

Comment: Ideally, you should be using a virtual environment and have your libraries defined in a `requirements.txt`, `Pipfile`, `project.toml`, or similar. Then you could create a new virtual environment using Python 3.9 and reinstall everything easily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install python packages from older version to newer version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473864/how-to-install-python-packages-from-older-version-to-newer-version)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a requirements .txt file by:
pip freeze > requirements.txt

and after installing python 3.9 type(in the same directory in which you made the requirements.txt):
pip install -r my_packages.txt

As shown in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5a0fhu/how_do_i_move_every_packages_pip_installed_for/)